# use dropdown value to return PHP query results

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

This is my first attempt at using ajax to run a php query. **My main goal is to pull data from my database without the page refreshing.** I have a dropdown menu where the options are different categories of products.

```
    <form id='theForm'>
    <select name="category" id='category'>
     <option value="">Select Food Category</option>
     <option value="Dairy" >Dairy</option>
     <option value="Fruits" >Fruits</option>
     <option value="Grains" >Grains</option>
     <option value="Nuts &amp; Beans" >Nuts &amp; Beans</option>
     <option value="Oils" >Oils</option>
     <option value="Other" >Other</option>
     <option value="Protein Foods" >Protein Foods</option>
     <option value="Supplements" >Supplements</option>
     <option value="Vegetables" >Vegetables</option>
    </select>
    </form>
<div id='result'><div>
```

I am trying to use the following Ajax call to send the selected value of the dropdown menu to a PHP query of my database to return the names of the all the products is that category into a separate dropdown.

AJAX Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#category").change(function()
{
var selectedcat=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "getfoods.php",
            data: {q:selectedcat},
            type:'POST',
            success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
            },
            error:function(msg){
            alert("Error: "+msg);
            }
        });//end ajax request     
});//end category change
});//end doc ready
```

The php code is the following:

```
<?php
$q = $_POST['q'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ". mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($con,productDB);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Category = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<form method='post'  id='form1'><select id='food_dd'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<option value='". $row['FoodName']."'>".$row['FoodName']."</option>";
  }
echo "</select></form>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

After a lot of research trying to find examples I still cannot get this request to work. I have tried with success to make this type of call in javascript, but I would really like to use JQuery.

Thank you in advance!
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
  $('#result').html(data);
```

instead of

```
 $('#result').text(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the inconvenience. I just realized now that the php file got moved into a different directory. The code is working now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about SQL injection. Every input from the client has to be considered hostile. The way it is now, it's child's play to break out of the SQL query and do whatever you like. It might work technically with sane input but don't take any chances.

Furthermore you should check if $_POST['q'] exists and you should sanetize the input. In addition read about prepared statements and PDO.